Selenium emulate site you came from
When I am opening the url via link https://kinoxor.pro/650-mir-druzhba-zhvachka-2024-05-06-19-54.html -- I have an error - Internal Server Error

But when I paste the link to the search engine https://yandex.ru/search/?text=https%3A%2F%2Fkinoxor.pro%2F650-mir-druzhba-zhvachka-2024-05-06-19-54.html&search_source=dzen_desktop_safe&lr=213
I can open the site (the first site in the results)

I am opening site with help of selenium
from selenium import webdriver 
   

driver = webdriver.Chrome()    
url = "https://kinoxor.pro/650-mir-druzhba-zhvachka-2024-05-06-19-54.html"   
driver.get(url) 

I think that I should emulate the site I came from (add some headers / meta-information)
I mean I should emulate that my previous site was yandex.ru (I don't want to really go to yandex)
Is it possible in Python?

If you click on the url yandex suggest you will find that it resolves at different url: https://10mot.kinoxor.pro/650-mir-druzhba-zhvachka-2024-05-12-20-31.html, and not into your initial url. I guess by adding 10mot into url may work. Since, selenium uses browser I don't think you need to add extra headers.

I think you can try selenium wire instead.
https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#intercepting-requests-and-responses
Install it using pip install selenium-wire
You could try something like this,
from seleniumwire import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def interceptor(request):
    del request.headers['Referer'] 
    request.headers['Referer'] = 'https://yandex.ru/'

driver.request_interceptor = interceptor

url = "https://kinoxor.pro/650-mir-druzhba-zhvachka-2024-05-06-19-54.html"   

driver.get(url)

If you just want to use selenium, you can try this,
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
referer = "https://www.yandex.ru"
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--referer={referer}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = "https://kinoxor.pro/650-mir-druzhba-zhvachka-2024-05-06-19-54.html"
driver.get(url)


However, it might not work as I don't think selenium has built in referrer spoofing.

Thank you, I am looking for pure selenium solution

@mascai take a look at my answer, I have updated it

Than you for the update, but it's not working

thats because selenium does not have referrer spoofing, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732463/setting-referer-in-selenium
